# How to start a Windows process minimized using WMIC?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, process, minimize, wmic

Is there a way to start a process from a Windows 7 batch file (or from the command-line) using `WMIC`?  I am basically looking for the equivalent of `START /MIN`.

And not that I need it, but in case someone else might, what would be the `START /MAX` equivalent using `WMIC`?

Answer (score 1):

Not using `wmic`, but I think it does what you need:

```
powershell.exe Start-Process -WindowStyle Minimized -PassThru notepad
```

Output contains PID:

```
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
     18       3     1232       1616       0,03  51784   1 notepad
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write a vbs script. From [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389388(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389388%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394375(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394375%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
Const SW_NORMAL = 1
strComputer = "."
strCommand = "Notepad.exe" 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
    & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

' Configure the Notepad process to show a window
Set objStartup = objWMIService.Get("Win32_ProcessStartup")
Set objConfig = objStartup.SpawnInstance_
objConfig.ShowWindow = SW_NORMAL

' Create Notepad process
Set objProcess = objWMIService.Get("Win32_Process")
intReturn = objProcess.Create _
    (strCommand, Null, objConfig, intProcessID)
If intReturn <> 0 Then
    Wscript.Echo "Process could not be created." & _
        vbNewLine & "Command line: " & strCommand & _
        vbNewLine & "Return value: " & intReturn
Else
    Wscript.Echo "Process created." & _
        vbNewLine & "Command line: " & strCommand & _
        vbNewLine & "Process ID: " & intProcessID
End If
```

Comment: You do know programs started remotely are invisible.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback, but unfortunately VBS is not an option for me.  But you are saying that this is not possible with WMIC then?

Comment: How will you pass an object as a command line parameter? And WHY, they are invisible so pointless to make them minimised.

Comment: I am not starting a remote program nor am I passing an object.  I would like to start a local process minimized, that is all.  Perhaps an example:  (1) Run cmd.exe, (2) start /min notepad.exe => this works, now (3) wmic process call create notepad.exe => does not minimize it, so my question is how to do this using WMIC, if it's even possible.  I need the ProcessId, which WMIC provides but START does not.  There may be multiple instances of this process already running so I can't use tasklist to find the ProcessId.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to search for a equivalent of `start /min` (unless there are additional requirements). Just use `start /min`

```
wmic process call create "cmd /c start /min notepad.exe"
```

Of course `/max` works the same.

Comment: _unless there are additional requirements_

Yes, there are additional requirements.  I need the ProcessId of the process that is started, which you won't get by this method.